# Strange error in usage story feed: This story was invalidated because

Tags: facebook-graph-api

Facebook was automatically publishing my application's usage story feeds. But I saw a strange error at app usage story feed panel tonight(At the right hand side of the screen). Which was:

This story was invalidated because: The object at http://apps.facebook.com/onlinekullanicilar/ doesn't have a title.

But my application do have title tags (both title and meta og:title elements)

Any opinions?

Comment: I've also started seeing this today.  It's quite annoying... likely a facebook code-push in progress.

Comment: I have been refreshing and refreshing hoping an answer will appear. just launched a FB game today and this ticker error message is looking ugly!

Comment: Same problem. I tried title tags but no results. I notice none of facebook bloggers use title tag in their example code so I don't think it has something to do with these tags. I believe this is another variable they want us to use like $sign_request which I never had to use before.

Comment: I think it is clearly a bug from facebook, it is now showing another type of error - instead of showing "UserName is using GameName right now", it is now showing "UserName is using Story in ticker about using an app right now". wat an epic failure

Comment: Is there a raised issue in FB Jira for this?

Comment: Same issue here on all of my applications that are non game?  Any solution to this yet?

Comment: Seems to be a facebook bug. I had it with my app, changed the category for the app like it says here and that solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem this morning.

Justnow I tried to checkout whether my application is a Game application.

I saw that my app is categorized as "others", so I changed it to "Game"->"Action"

And voila! I suddenly see the correct ticker again!

Can you try whether it works on you too.

Comment: That's good, but the drop-down choice of category does not contain appropriate classification for my app, so I put Game>Action as well. There used to be 'Just for fun' category, which my app belongs to, but it's not available anymore. I wonder if FB stuff bans my app due to the fact it misleads it is a game, when it's not, but it's THEIR fault!

Answer (score 1):

I have just tried it and works as you said. The error disappear.

The problem now is that my app is within the Sports category and once chosen the error appear but when I change it to game --> Arcade, works.

I think it must be a mistake from facebook.